# Function of ,c in R

Tags: r

I came across an example online and was wondering what this line mean?
1) What does ,c does in the first line? While I understand that `c` is used to combine, I am not sure what it does here?

```
monthly_ts<-ts(monthly_sales[,c('DAUTONSA')])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, c is used to create a vector that selects the column "DAUTONSA" from the dataset, i.e., it subsets the dataset. The example below achieves the same thing with generic data.

```
library(tidyverse)
x <- tibble(
    time = 1:100
)

ts(x[,c("time")] )
```

Comment: Sorry am new to R. But wouldn't `ts(x$time)` achieve the similar outcome?

Comment: Yes, they are two ways to achieve the same outcome, but in one you are selecting the column as a vector, while in the other you are subsetting the data frame to contain only the columns specified in the c(). If this answer solves your problem, would you mind upvoting and approving it?

Comment: @HarroCyranka  If I understand your point correctly,  using  the `drop=FALSE` option in `[<-`  will do the same thing.

Comment: note that tibbles behave differently from base-R data frames in this respect.  Tibbles always return a 1-column data frame; in base R, it depends on the value of `drop` argument (`TRUE` by default, as @CarlWitthoft suggests)